# How to Center a Div Within a Div, for Multi-platform Web Design

Tags: html, css

So I have a slider and a slider wrapper. Both are absolutely positioned elements. The layout I currently have looks great on a desktop monitor (1920x1080). However not so good on a smaller laptop screen (the slider is shifted to the right and so out of center alignment). Below you will find the CSS for both the container of the slider and the slider itself.

```
#MasterSlider_container{
    height: 570px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 20%; 
}

#slider1_container{
    left: 21%;
    top: 7%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

How do I center the slider in this div box so that when I view it on a laptop or a PC screen, it will appear in the middle completely and entirely on both viewing platforms.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/3593530

Comment: Already did, doesn't work.

Comment: why you using absolute positioning...use relative for both then make margin auto for inner div

Comment: What @sanjayduttindia said. CSS cannot do what you ask if you need to use absolute positioning. If you do not use absolute positioning this is very simple to do with CSS.

Comment: Now all my boxes are messed up, the container has gone straight to the top of the screen ! How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#MasterSlider_container{
height: 570px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
top: 20%; 
}

#slider1_container{
margin:0 auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 8px;
position: absolute; 
width:50%;
}
```

Change the width according to your needs. Only if you set the width you can see the container being centered

Comment: Doesn't work. I have literally tried everything I have seen on the internet and im running it in a Google chrome live preview.

Comment: you saw in the fiddle how it is centered. may be your sequencess of css is not letting your div to be centered.

Comment: I discovered what it was, I had set position: absolute in the html file so it contradicted all my relative positioning attempts, ignorance is bliss...